# How to reshape this complicated data frame?

Tags: r, reshape

Here is first 4 rows of my data;

```
  X...Country.Name Country.Code                               Indicator.Name
1           Turkey          TUR           Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)
2           Turkey          TUR Unemployment, total (% of total labor force)
3      Afghanistan          AFG           Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)
4      Afghanistan          AFG Unemployment, total (% of total labor force)
     Indicator.Code     X2010
1 NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG  5.675740
2    SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS 11.900000
3 NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG  9.437322
4    SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS        NA
```

I want my data reshaped into two colums, one of each Indicator code, and I want each row correspond to a country, something like this;

```
Country Name NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS
Turkey       5.6         11.9
Afghanistan  9.43        NA
```

I think I could do this with Excel, but I want to learn the R way, so that I don't need to rely on excel everytime I have a problem. [Here is dput](https://gist.github.com/raw/4655137/31c3901cb48e1b8e4747f9c7d0106558f366ce97/mydata) of data if you need it.

Edit: I actually want 3 colums, one for each indicator and one for the country's name.

Comment: FYI, you can also use `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` instead of posting your full dataset.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks. I am new learner and don't know those things yet :) Data is not something private though, so it is not a problem.

Comment: @Arun, also, I feel that questions should be as "self-contained" as possible, that is, not relying on data being stored elsewhere, for example Dropbox or Github. There is always the chance that the OP will delete the data from those places, and that makes the questions much less useful in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sticking with base R, use `reshape`. I took the liberty of cleaning up the column names. Here, I'm only showing you a few rows of the output. Remove `head` to see the full output. This assumes your `data.frame` is named "mydata".

```
names(mydata) <- c("CountryName", "CountryCode", 
                   "IndicatorName", "IndicatorCode", "X2010")
head(reshape(mydata[-c(2:3)], 
             direction = "wide", 
             idvar = "CountryName", 
             timevar = "IndicatorCode"))
#       CountryName X2010.NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG X2010.SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS
# 1          Turkey                5.675740                 11.9
# 3     Afghanistan                9.437322                   NA
# 5         Albania                3.459343                   NA
# 7         Algeria               16.245617                 11.4
# 9  American Samoa                      NA                   NA
# 11        Andorra                      NA                   NA
```

Another option in base R is `xtabs`, but `NA` gets replaced with `0`:

```
head(xtabs(X2010 ~ CountryName + IndicatorCode, mydata))
#                 IndicatorCode
# CountryName      NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS
#   Afghanistan             9.437322            0.0
#   Albania                 3.459343            0.0
#   Algeria                16.245617           11.4
#   American Samoa          0.000000            0.0
#   Andorra                 0.000000            0.0
#   Angola                 22.393924            0.0
```

The result of `xtabs` is a `matrix`, so if you want a `data.frame`, wrap the output with `as.data.frame.matrix`.